# Better way to copy from list to list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, foreach

A Unit can have Many Prices associated with it (different prices apply to different times of the year).

[image]

Unit "A" have prices in 3 seasons (3 diferent prices) and Unit "B" & "C" also have 3 season and pices. Now I need to Copy startDate and endDate form unit "A" all 3 season in unit "B" & "C" but keep prices of unit "B" & "C" only change startDate and endDate. What to use and how IList or IEnumerable something else? I think that too many times If and  foreach...

I try this... But must be better way any sugestion?

```
            //select A Unit (Master unit)
        _masterUnit = Core.Model.Unit.GetById(Convert.ToInt32(ddlAllUnits.SelectedValue));

        IList<Core.Model.Unit> allUnits = Core.Model.Unit.GetUnits();

        IList<Price> _masterPrices = Price.GetPricesOfUnit(_masterUnit.UnitId);

        int mp;
        int xp;

        foreach (Core.Model.Unit unit in allUnits)
        {
            if ((unit.UnitId != _masterUnit.UnitId) && (_masterPrices.Count == unit.AllUnitPrices.Count))
            {
                mp = 1;
                xp = 1;

                IList<Price> _unitPrices = Price.GetPricesOfUnit(unit.UnitId);
                foreach (Price _pricex in _masterPrices)
                {
                   xp = 1;
                    foreach (Price price in _unitPrices)
                    { 
                        if (mp == xp)
                        {  
                            Price newPrice = null;
                            newPrice = Price.GetById(price.PriceId);

                            newPrice.UnitId = price.UnitId;
                            newPrice.UnitPrice = price.UnitPrice;
                            newPrice.StartDate = _pricex.StartDate;
                            newPrice.EndDate = _pricex.EndDate;
                            newPrice.ExtraBed = price.ExtraBed;
                            newPrice.Save();
                        }xp++;
                    }
                    mp++;
                }   
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I thinks the better way is using the SQL commands instead of c# code

Comment: This whole thing looks pretty suspicious. You should really separate your concerns. As far as I can see it's about (1) identify the source unit price entries (2) identify the target unit price entries (3) ensure that the entries count matches (4) order them by date (5) iterate them in parallel (source + target together, not parallel as in parallel computing) (6) change target date ranges according to source. You should definitely write separate methods for different aspects of your update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all that's some confusing code you've got there.

Secondly I think I've managed to simplify the logic.

```
    //gets unit A
    _masterUnit = Core.Model.Unit.GetById(Convert.ToInt32(ddlAllUnits.SelectedValue));

    //gets prices for A
    IList<Price> _masterPrices = Price.GetPricesOfUnit(_masterUnit.UnitId);

    //gets all Units 
    IList<Unit> allUnits = Core.Model.Unit.GetUnits();

    foreach(Unit unit in allUnits){

        //gets units price
        var unitPrices = Price.GetPricesOfUnit(_masterUnit.UnitId);

        for(int i = 0; i < unitPrices.length(); i++){

            //replaces start, end date with that of master unit    
            unitPrices[i].StartDate = _masterPrices[i].StartDate;                         
            unitPrices[i].EndDate= _masterPrices[i].EndDate;

            unitPrices[i].Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this work whit some change `for(int i = 0; i < unitPrices.length(); i++) ` to  `for (int i = 0; i < unitPrices.LongCount(); i++) ` LongCount and  ` var unitPrices = Price.GetPricesOfUnit(_masterUnit.UnitId); ` _masterUnit.UnitId to unit.UnitId

Answer (score 0):

That database design is weird.

Sounds like the data is messed up?

Why would you need to set the StartDate and EndDate to that of some other unit?

Either way...the steps to perform this are...

1. Get the prices for the master unit
2. Get the units you are concerned with updating
3. This is where you run into a problem. You dont know which price item to update to which date. For example, if Unit B has prices $5, $10, and $20, how do you know what StartDate and EndDate goes with what price?

Did you design this? You need to rethink the design. I would add a new table, PriceBlock (int PriceBlock, date StartDate, date EndDate), and each Price will be mapped to a PriceBlock.

Comment: 1st Season is always lower dates then second season and second season have lower dates then 3th season ane etc...All units have same number of season. So I make sort orderBy start date someting lik this `code` IList<Price> _masterPrices = Price.GetPricesOfUnit(_masterUnit.UnitId);
            IEnumerable<Price> query_order = _masterPrices.OrderBy(f => f.StartDate); `code`